# Measure User Weight By Kinect Sensor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, kinect, kinect-sdk

I know how to measure user height with Kinect sensor.

Is it also possibile to measure weight?

Comment: Hate to nit-pick but in your question you've made the comment "I can measure user height." and then said "But i wanna measure height too.". I'd presume that you wish to measure the users weight instead?

Answer (score 2):

You may ask about the sensor.

The kinect sensor is a 3D point cloud generating sensor.
It operates by throwing a randomized pattern on surfaces, and then record the pattern with a camera.

The distortion of the pattern reveals how the surface that bounces the pattern is shaped in 3D

With the various SDK's to the kinect sensor, you get access to some of the popular methods that can be applied to a point cloud, containing a human beings surface.

This could be something like posture estimation, where a simple skeleton is scaled to fit the point cloud as best as possible, and then it provides you angles of joints, and length of limbs.
Including height of a person.

To do weight, you would either need a different type of sensor that can measure mass, or estimate it from the persons volume.

You would need to recreate, (or guess) the persons volume, as the point cloud may be incomplete, or at best, only show the front of the person, so depth, and similar information (like size of buttocks etc.) will not be shown in the same data as the data for the stomach..

You can use algorithms like ICP (Iterative Closest Point) for this, if the person can be asked to rotate in front of the kinect. When this is done, a complete body scan is done, and a complete point cloud will be available for the person.

Using this, the surface can be recreated, using one of many algorithms for recreating surface descriptions from pointclouds. I have not found one I like yet, but it probably exists.

given this, you can now calculate the volume of a person.

All you have to do from here, is to guess the density of the person.
This requires some knowledge of the persons fat to muscle to bone ratios, but you may be able to infer that from the body shape (I'm just guessing that there may be a relation) when this density is estimated, you can multiply it onto the volume, and voila, a fairly accurate weight estimate is found.